# How to extend to "organise imports" command handler in eclipse jdt?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, static-methods, eclipse-jdt

I want to extend the "organize imports" command of eclipse jdt by adding a sub-task that performs a static import of all applicable methods.  Currently we can only achive this by a manual import of every method.

My questions are:

1. Where can I find the "organise imports" command handler?
2. Where can I find the "add static import" command handler?

Answer (score 2):

Organize Imports uses an old style action rather than a command handler.

The code is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OrganizeImportsAction`